# OpenCV Facedetect sample not working

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I'm trying to run the Facedetect sample using OpenCV, I compiled the code the build_all.sh file.

Then I ran the code with

```
sudo ./facedetect --cascade="../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" --nested-cascade="../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml" --scale=1.3 lena.jpg
```

A few instructions are displayed

```
This program demonstrates the cascade recognizer. Now you can use Haar or LBP features.
This classifier can recognize many kinds of rigid objects, once the appropriate classifier is trained.
It's most known use is for faces.
Usage:
./facedetect [--cascade=<cascade_path> this is the primary trained classifier such as frontal face]
   [--nested-cascade[=nested_cascade_path this an optional secondary classifier such as eyes]]
   [--scale=<image scale greater or equal to 1, try 1.3 for example>]
   [--try-flip]
   [filename|camera_index]

see facedetect.cmd for one call:
./facedetect --cascade="../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" --nested-cascade="../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml" --scale=1.3

During execution:
    Hit any key to quit.
    Using OpenCV version 2.4.8

Processing 1 --cascade=../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
  from which we have cascadeName= ../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
Processing 2 --nested-cascade=../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml
Processing 3 --scale=1.3
 from which we read scale = 1.3
Processing 4 lena.jpg
```

And in the end I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/userk/Development/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 483
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
      what():  /home/userk/Development/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.8/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow
```

The packages libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config were already installed. Do you guys have any advice?

**SOLVED:**

As Berak suggested, I recompiled opencv from its main directory with:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: the missing packages had to be installed when *compiling the opencv libs*, not when compiling your prog. in other words, you might have to recompile opencv to make it work.

Comment: avoid stupid package managers, get the src code and recompile.